# Stopping the animation of GIF

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios8

Here i am using the [uiimage-from-animated-gif](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif) library to show an animated GIF through a `UIImage`. It's working, but I need to stop the animation, `imageView` after one complete revolution.

The following code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"dove-animate" withExtension:@"gif"];
self.imageView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864292/uiimageviewanimatedgif-always-loops and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744682/display-animated-gif-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

```
url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"dove-animate" withExtension:@"gif"];
UIImage *testImage = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
self.imageView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
self.imageView.animationImages = testImage.images;
self.imageView.animationDuration = testImage.duration;
self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
self.imageView.image = testImage.images.lastObject;
[self.imageView startAnimating];



Use the above code it will works
```